# Creating API's with 3rd party company

Tags: google-admin-sdk

We are looking to use Google API's to connect to a 3rd party platform and capture such data including email address, certain customer specific content to include in the email, the subject line, and we need a "tag" to notify google to send the email. We have a business G-suite account. How can we set up these API's?

Comment: Not enough info for reasonable answer, but from what I guessed: have you considered using Firebase Authentication https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth?authuser=0 ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you would simply need to set up your Google Developer's console [here](https://console.developers.google.com/) for the Google API's you want to use, **following the steps indicated in the specific API documentation.**

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) you can find a list of Google API's with the links to their corresponding documentation where you will find more information about each including setup guides or samples.

For example, [this is the Google's Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) where you can find a reference to achieve what you are aiming for.